# What is this layout called?

Tags: android, layout

I am new to android development.

I want to know what kind of layout/control is displayed in the image below?

[image]

It is card view or recycle view or something else?

Comment: Its is Custom Dialog ,in which you can set listView or recycleview.

Comment: Thanks guys, i figured out that we can do this with Dialog. I thought Dialog only displays dialog boxes, but after going through your inputs, even we can load any layouts within the Dialog as we do in Activity. Your replies help me.

Answer (score 2):

The Layout may be a kind of Dialog.
However, there could be several ways to handle the list inside it; it may be:

- a listView
- a recyclerView
- a group of radioButtons
- several textViews and imageViews
- ...

It depends on what is suitable for your project!

Answer (score 0):

That is an dialog box with expandableListView